# Can MemSQL be deployed under YARN?

Tags: hadoop-yarn, mesos, singlestore

MemSQL is a in-memory database and makes effective use of cores on the machines it has been deployed.

I want to deploy in the same database on the same infrastructure where my other ecosystem tools are running. What are possibilities of MemSQL working under a resource management framework like YARN or Mesos?

I could not find much information on Google, wondering if it is possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MemSQL can be deployed with Mesos - we have a Mesosphere framework for MemSQL which makes it extremely easy to deploy, see http://blog.memsql.com/how-to-deploy-memsql-on-the-mesosphere-dcos-2/. We don't currently have a similar framework for YARN but it certainly can be done.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Currently our environment makes use of YARN heavily. I would be interested in knowing if is there a plan down in the roadmap to have YARN support?

Comment: Do you have any documents to deploy Mem under YARN?